# Can Cordova, Phonegap etc. be used for building mobile web applications

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I want to build a mobile web application (please note that a mobile web application is different than a native app), I have searched but still my confusion is not clear on whether I can use Cordova, Phonegap and similar frameworks to build mobile web application?

Or these frameworks are used for build only native apps but one can use his HTML, CSS, Javascript skills for development, but in the end app will be a native app and has to be downloaded and installed on specific device?

Or is it that apps built using these frameworks can be directly accessed using browser (which is nothing but being a mobile web app) even though app is not installed on device?

Comment: Native apps are NOT built in HTML,CSS and JS. What you're talking about is Hybrid apps. They are ran in a WebVIew.

Comment: @Stefan Ok, so then my question is are hybrid apps nothing but "mobile web applications"? And is an app built using Cordava or Phonegap has to be download first before it can be used?

Answer (score 1):

If by mobile web application you mean a mobile friendly web application, then cordova has nothing to do with this. If you mean, building a mobile application via a webview using html+css then cordova is what you want. You can also use frameworks such as Ionic to help build a cordova hybrid app.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, it helps me a bit. Now thats where my whole confusion is - is hybrid app different than mobile web application? Also, is an app built using Cordava or Phonegap has to be download first before it can be used?

Comment: A hybrid app is an app that has the same source code for both iOS and Android. All apps (native and hybrid) have to be downloaded and installed first.

Comment: @pjj Yes, apps built using Cordova/Ionic/ReactNative are mobile apps that need to be installed on the device. They are hybrid apps that are written using javascript/html/css. They are still mobile apps, but are not written in the device's native language (Objective-C/Swift/Android).

Comment: Ahh, I have a bit better view now, so it means hybrids apps are just another flavor or subset of native apps but its just that if you make a native app for Android then it will only be for Android but if you make a "hybrid" app for then same Android "hybrid" app can be download and installed for iOS etc., did I understood it right way?

Comment: Long story short, an hybrid app will use a native container (Java for Android, Swift for iOS) that will contain a webview with your code. At this point I encourage you to read http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/

Comment: @MattM and Eric: I have read about that you wrap Cordava or Phonegap around an existing app, so my question here is that - you can only wrap a Cordava or Phonegap around a existing app (and that existing app has to be a native app) so that it becomes a hybrid app OR Cordava or Phonegap can also be wrapped around a mobile web application (a mobile web application which is built using jQuery mobile or alike frameworks and cannot be dowloaded but can only be accessed over browser)?

Comment: @pjj See Eric's comment. If you're interested in Angular, look into Ionic (as Eric suggested). There are cool tutorials you can do.

Comment: "I have read about that you wrap Cordava or Phonegap around an existing app" - NO. The container will be created as you compile.